# Microsoft CRM 2011 On Demand Development and Test Environments

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, ondemand

Does anyone have recommendations on the best way to set up development and testing environments for Microsoft CRM 2011 On Demand?

The recommendations I have seen so far include:

- Paying for another account with only one user
- Creating a VM
- Going with a partner hosted environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to be a little more specific.  What's wrong with the 3 you have listed?  Is it cost, it is the time to configure?

That being said, what I do is sign up for the [free 30 day trial](https://signin.crm5.dynamics.com/portal/signup/signup.aspx?lc=1033&orglcid=en-AU).

First, sign up for a new [Windows Live account](http://home.live.com/).

Second, [click here](http://home.live.com/) to sign up for the 30 day account.

Third, I always write down the login & url because I always forget them.

I'll have anywhere from 1 - 5 of these running at once.

The main benefit is the control this gives me.  Since you can't access the SQL server directly with [On Demand](http://crm.dynamics.com/en-us/on-demand), it forces you to make your configurations & customizations the correct way.

Your other option is to setup a VM environment and create a new instance every time you need a clean setup.  This is not my preferred option since you need good hardware to run the environment (otherwise the performance penalty is huge)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I think we will be going with the separate instances of CRM Online.  The problem with the trial method is that it is temporary, and we will need an ongoing dev/test setup.